# what approach should I take in heavy iterations?

Tags: java, boost-iterators

I got this Java webapp (JSP+Struts+Hibernate+MySQL+tomcat6) in which there are like 20000 users right now and the number is growing up rapidly. I have to rank all the users periodically. The ranking process involves lots of objects and hibernate actions and it's fairly heavy. Talking java, unfortunately I must iterate on all of the users and apply this procedure in them one by one. this method sucks out lots of the server's resources.

on the other hand I might be able to run all these actions in a stored procedure on the MySQL side. I'm pretty sure the code there will be a complete mess and troublesome to modify later on. although the performance would be much more better this way but software engineering principles wouldn't take this solution nicely.

what do you suggest?

Comment: 20000 isn't a large number, so it must be an algorithm issue. What is your Big-O complexity? Are you running this in a separate process?

Comment: Could it be that hibernate loads to much? Do you use lazy loading? I find that logging on debug level will show you all the queries hibernate does. Are they all necessary?

Comment: @tjameson: I got 3 nested loops but in comparison to the most outer one the complexity of two inner loops are insignificant. Considering n as number of users, the complexity is something around 250n.

Comment: Why not export this to a separate application to run on a chron-job at like 2 am when nobody is on? That should minimize strain.

Comment: @extraneon: I do use hibernate lazy indeed. all collections and stuff are lazy and they're loaded once for each user in every iteration. but this repetitive hibernate actions may also lead to low performance I suppose. right?

Comment: @tjameson: well actually the feature is the way that users must be able to see their rank as updated as possible. Running ranking once a midnight wouldn't be an option here. Forgot to say that I run this process in a TimerTask so it's being run in a separate thread.

Comment: How often is it being run? Once an hour, once a minute, once a second? The more times you run it, the worse it gets. Can you do some kind of method where you keep everything sorted? That way you don't have to reprocess everything everytime.

Comment: usually once an hour, worst case every 30 minutes. well the respective data are changed every time and all the consequences seem to be necessary but I should give more thought to the algorithm in there anyway. BTW in my own PC (3GB RAM, 2.5GHz Core2) it takes like 5 minutes to run this.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously much more efficient in SQL.  The real problem is that you are using hibernate and so have lost control over your schema which is why a solution like iBatis, although less popular, makes more sense - because it allows you to switch to SQL when that is the more appropriate tool for the job.

Given that you have chosen hibernate, are you sure that you can't push the API it provides into doing this?  Have you looked in detail at the criteria API?  That includes associations - it might be possible to shoe-horn what you want in there and so keep the logic more closely associated with the classes.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: thanks for the reply, well I suppose anything with criteria can be implemented with HQL too and criteria is no better than HQL in performance. I actually tried to narrow down my needed data in every iteration using HQL. it made the process like 3000 times slower! I kinda came to understanding that it's the hibernate which makes this process snail.

Comment: that sounds strange.  you may not have the right indices defined - get a copy of the SQL that's executed and then use "explain" in mysql to see if you have any linear scans.  hibernate itself is no worse than anything else - sql should be faster because you don't need to go through all the trouble of creating objects, and it should have things appropriately sorted (indexed) to access the data as fast as possible.  so if sql or hsql is slower then it's most likely an index problem.

Comment: thanks buddy, I'll dig it more...